# Document.on.dragover gets broken by unrelated code

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript file is [here](https://github.com/schart/simple-filedirectory/blob/master/script.js). Basically my website is sort of a command prompt style website where I enter commands to do certain functions like file uploading. I also have a "drag & drop" upload function, which looks like this:

```js
$(document).on('dragover', 'body', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#fileupload").addClass('ishovered');
    $(".dragtext").show();
});
$(document).on('dragleave', 'body', function(e) {
    $("#fileupload").removeClass('ishovered');
    $(".dragtext").hide();
});
$(document).on('drop', 'body', function(e) {
    $("#fileupload").removeClass('ishovered');
    $(".dragtext").hide();
});
```

Now this works fine on the website load. But after I run this seemingly unrelated code:

```js
[...]
} else if (value.match("^clear") || value.match("^cls")) {
    if ($(".isup").attr("value") == "tr") {
        $("#container").append("<span class='code'>" + value + "</span><span class='cmd-cont'>error: please answer yes/no first</span>");
        updateScroll();
    } else {
        $("#container").html(""); /* This is what usually runs, and for some reason breaks the drag & drop upload */
    }
}
[...]
function updateScroll() {
    var element = document.getElementById("container");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}
```

For some reason running this code breaks the drag & drop upload, as in the website doesn't respond to files being hovered over after that code has been executed.

[Live demo](http://simple-filedirectory.underbakke.net/?k=YOURURLPASSWORD) (you can recreate by trying to pull and file in to the website after load, then typing "cls" or "clear" and then try to drag a file in again)

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I missed that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#container").html("");` destroys the `#fileupload` form (because it's a child of #`container`)